# XPATH for excel xml format

Tags: excel, xml, xpath, xslt

I'm trying to figure out the XPATH for the following excel xml format and I'm hitting a brick wall.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>8700</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>11355</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>60</WindowTopY>
  <TabRatio>815</TabRatio>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s2">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s3">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="dddd, mmmm d, yyyy"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s4">
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10.00" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s5">
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10.00" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s6">
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10.00" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" ss:Underline="Single"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s21">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="CenterAcrossSelection" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="18.00" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s22">
   <Alignment ss:Horizontal="CenterAcrossSelection" ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Arial" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="10.00" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0"/>
   <Borders>
    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
   </Borders>
   <Interior ss:Color="#C0C0C0" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="ClassList">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="256" ss:ExpandedRowCount="150000" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
   <Column ss:Index="1" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="2" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="3" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="4" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="5" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="6" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="7" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="8" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="9" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="10" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="11" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="12" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="13" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="14" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="15" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="16" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="17" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="18" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="19" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="20" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="21" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="22" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="23" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="24" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="25" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="26" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="27" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="28" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="29" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="30" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="31" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="32" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="33" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Column ss:Index="34" ss:Width="70.00"/>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s4"><Data ss:Type="String">Some Text</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s4"><Data ss:Type="String">Summer 2023</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Data Source: Somewhere</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Report ID : 07</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s3"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2023-09-29</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">10:20:01 PM</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Franks</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Office of Frank</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Reporting System</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
   </Row>
   <Row>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s5"><Data ss:Type="String">Parameters:all</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">College</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Department</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Subject</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Catalog Nbr</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Section</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Session</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Class Nbr</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Enr Mngment Flag</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Instruction Mode</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Instruction Mode Descr</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">APDB Learning Mode</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">APDB Learning Mode Descr</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Multiple Meetings</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Title</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Units</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Components</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Days</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Begin Time</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">End Time</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Facility</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Facility Cap</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Room Fill %</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Enrollment Capacity</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Reserve Capacity</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Enrollment Total</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Reserve Enrollment</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Class Fill %</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Waitlist Total</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Unused Permits</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Enrollment Status</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Class Status</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Instructor</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">GE</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data ss:Type="String">Combined Section</Data>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">55</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">710</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">THE</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> 122</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">01</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">S1S</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">   10026</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">04</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Asynch</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">01</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Asynchronous </Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">21st Century</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">3</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">LEC</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NA</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Online</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">20</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">20</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">100</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Closed</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Active</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Glue,Frank</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">AREA: 51</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
    </Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

What I'm trying to get out is the data in the Rows.  I've tried all kinds of different xpath combos and the best I can do is get the window widths at the beginning.

I'm specifically interested in getting the headers that are found at:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s6"><Data
```

And then the data that follows at:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">THE</Data>
```

Again - I've had zero luck and would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Show also the exact result you expect to get (as code). P.S. Usually you would want to extract data from a specific column identified by number, or by the text in a header row, not by its style.

Comment: You can download foxe (free) from http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm. Open the xml file,Select the node you like and right click to have the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super-simple XSLT stylesheet that converts a document in Excel 2002/2003 XML (SpreadsheetML) format to CSV (without considering possible quotes, commas or carriage returns contained inside the cells):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/ss:Workbook">
    <xsl:for-each select="ss:Worksheet/ss:Table/ss:Row">
        <xsl:for-each select="ss:Cell">
            <xsl:value-of select='ss:Data'/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```